# How to convert Agda's with statement to a helper function?

Tags: agda

I read [here](https://plfa.github.io/Relations/) that

> Every use of with is equivalent to defining a helper function

But I couldn't get it working with trying to re-implement a with-clause (which itself came from re-implementing the Agda `rewrite` clause. More specifically:

The original `rewrite` clause is:

```
even-comm : ∀ (m n : ℕ)
  → even (m + n)
    ------------
  → even (n + m)
even-comm m n ev rewrite +-comm m n  = ev
```

According to [here](https://plfa.github.io/Equality/#rewriting-expanded):

> The rewrite notation is in fact shorthand for an appropriate use of
> with abstraction:

```
even-comm′ : ∀ (m n : ℕ)
  → even (m + n)
    ------------
  → even (n + m)
even-comm′ m n ev with   m + n  | +-comm m n
...                  | .(n + m) | refl = ev
```

This works fine. I tried to understand how this `with` clause works by implementing it as a helper function. This is where I got stuck. What I have so far is:

```
even-comm'' : ∀ (m n : ℕ)
  → even (m + n)
    ------------
  → even (n + m)
even-comm'' m n ev = helper (m + n) (+-comm m n)
  where
  helper : ℕ → (m + n ≡ n + m) → even (n + m)
  helper mn prf = {!!}
```

This type-checks. But when I tried to case-analyze the proof for  `(+-comm m n)` on the only hole, I got an error:

```
I'm not sure if there should be a case for the constructor refl,
because I get stuck when trying to solve the following unification
problems (inferred index ≟ expected index):
  m₁ + n₁ ≟ n₁ + m₁
when checking that the expression ? has type even (n + m)
```

My question is:

1. How should I correctly implement the above with-clause using helper functions?
2. I don't really understand what the tutorial said about the proof for plus-commutativity reduces to/case-analyzes to `refl`. Could someone help explain why `refl` should be the only case for  `(+-comm m n)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The based identity type `_≡ n + m` is the type family inductively generated by a single constructor `refl : n + m ≡ n + m`. This means that for any identity of the form `p : x ≡ n + m`, where `x` is a *variable*, it suffices to consider the case where `x = n + m` and `p = refl`.

Hence you have to generalise over `m + n` in the type of `helper` (which is what `with`-abstraction does): the full translation should look like

```hs
even-comm'' m n ev = helper (m + n) (+-comm m n) ev
  where
  helper : (x : ℕ) → (x ≡ n + m) → even x → even (n + m)
  helper .(n + m) refl ev = ev
```

but you could also simplify this to

```hs
even-comm'' m n ev = helper (n + m) (+-comm m n)
  where
  helper : (x : ℕ) → (m + n ≡ x) → even x
  helper .(m + n) refl = ev
```

which corresponds to abstracting over `n + m` instead of `m + n` in the `with` clause.

Comment: I think it's worth a footnote (but only a footnote) that writing `helper (n + m) (+-comm m n)` in a hole and then pressing `C-c C-h` will produce the required type of `helper`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the accepted answer, I now understand the problem. Just for future reference, in my original attempt:

```
even-comm'' : ∀ (m n : ℕ)
  → even (m + n)
    ------------
  → even (n + m)
even-comm'' m n ev = helper (m + n) (+-comm m n)
  where
  helper : ℕ → (m + n ≡ n + m) → even (n + m)
  helper mn prf = {!!}
```

The signature of the `helper` function

```
  helper : ℕ → (m + n ≡ n + m) → even (n + m)
```

is problematic, because its first and second parameters are unrelated. But they should be linked in the sense that the first parameter should be the same as the LHS of the equality at the second parameter. (The second parameter should *depend on* the first parameter)

So, the signature should be (*a dependent function*)

```
helper : (m+n : ℕ) → (m+n ≡ n + m) → even (n + m)
```

So, this gives:

```
even-comm''' : ∀ (m n : ℕ)
  → even (m + n)
    ------------
  → even (n + m)
even-comm''' m n ev = helper (m + n) (+-comm m n)
  where
  helper : (m+n : ℕ) → (m+n ≡ n + m) → even (n + m)
  helper m+n rel = {!!}
```

where `rel` is the relation between the variable `m+n` and the term `n + m`.

Case-analyzing `rel` gives:

```
even-comm''' : ∀ (m n : ℕ)
  → even (m + n)
    ------------
  → even (n + m)
even-comm''' m n ev = helper (m + n) (+-comm m n)
  where
  helper : (m+n : ℕ) → (m+n ≡ n + m) → even (n + m)
  helper .(n + m) refl = {!!}
```

, with a right context:

```
Goal: even (n + m)
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
ev : even (m + n)
n  : ℕ
m  : ℕ
```

One last missing piece is to convert from `ev: even (m + n)` in the context to  `? : even (n + m)`. By definition of the variable `m+n`, `even (m + n)` is the same as `even m+n`, `ev: even (m + n)` itself is fixed and cannot be rewritten, but `ev1: even m+n` can. Adding `ev1: even m+n` to the parameter list, we have:

```
  helper : (m+n : ℕ) → (m+n ≡ n + m) → even m+n → even (n + m)
  helper m+n rel ev1 = {!!}
```

, which is the first option of the accepted answer. And it checks nicely after case-analyzing `rel`:

```
Goal: even (n + m)
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
ev1 : even (n + m)
ev  : even (m + n)
n   : ℕ
m   : ℕ
```

I guess this is just the long story of "generalizing" the term `m + n` into a variable `m+n` (and using it where necessary)

Comment: `ev` *is* available in `helper`, it just doesn't have the type you want. You have `even (m + n)`, you want `even (n + m)`. If you rewrite `n + m` to `m + n`, then you can give what you already have. If you rewrite `m + n` to `n + m`, then you need to "take a step back" and give the identity function.

Comment: @NaïmFavier Thanks for the hlep. I've updated the answer to hopefully fix the error. I guess I am not familiar with the concept of `generalization` yet, and need a way to persuade myself that `rewrite` can be mechanically translated into something.

Comment: You may want to read the [technical details](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.4.3/language/with-abstraction.html#technical-details) of generalisation.